# If/else statement not executing some node

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a code as below...

```
if(txtEditName.Text.Trim() == "" || txtEditAddress.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    lblBError.Enabled = true;
    lblBError.Visible = true;
    lblBError.Text = "Please provide the required field.";
    return;
}
else
{
    if(txtControl.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        if(DropDownClient.Enabled)
        {
            if(DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value == "select")
            {
                lblBError.Enabled = true;
                lblBError.Visible = true;
                lblBError.Text = "Please select Client.";
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(lblClientName.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                    VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail,(SELECT clientID FROM [CLIENT] WHERE cname='" + lblClientName.Text + "'))";
            }
            else
            {
                sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                    VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value + ")";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
            VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + Convert.ToInt32(txtControl.Text.Trim()) + " )";
        //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    }
}
```

The problem i am having is, some part of the code is not executing. When i run, it ignored the else part where

```
if(lblClientName.Text.Trim() != "")
{
}

else
{
    sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
        VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value + ")";
}
```

It jump the sql =" " for the else part and rather pass sql ass empty string. I am not sure why this happen? i check everything and all seem fine. Please can some one point what the problem is with the code?

Comment: may be because DropDownClient.Enabled is always true ? ..

Comment: When you try to use debugger what they tell you about lblClientName?

Comment: @NuruSalihu Can you add a debugging print statement to the `if` block. This will tell us if the condition `lblClientName.Text.Trim() != ""` is true or false.

Comment: Also, there's some serious code duplication going on there. I've formatted the code so it became more readable

Comment: Use `String.IsnullOrEmplty(lblClientName.Text.Trim())` instead

Comment: Hi, Only the else part of txtControl.text is not executing.Inorder word it does not check for lblClientName....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, using the `string.IsNullOrWhitespace`, or `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to help you out:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtEditName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtEditAddress.Text))
{
    lblBError.Enabled = true;
    lblBError.Visible = true;
    lblBError.Text = "Please provide the required field.";
    return;
}
else
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtControl.Text))
    {
        if (DropDownClient.Enabled && DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value == "select")
        {
            lblBError.Enabled = true;
            lblBError.Visible = true;
            lblBError.Text = "Please select Client.";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(lblClientName.Text))
            {
                sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                        VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail,(SELECT clientID FROM [CLIENT] WHERE cname='" + lblClientName.Text + "'))";
            }
            else
            {
                sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value + ")";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
            VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + Convert.ToInt32(txtControl.Text.Trim()) + " )";
                //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if none of the `sql= ...` lines are being executed, then it must be that the dropdownclient is enabled and its selected item = "select". There's nothing else I can see it could be.

EDIT:

I've tried to refactor your code. Forgive any mistakes, I didn't have much time to do this:

```
private bool EditFieldsAreValid()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEditName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEditAddress.Text))
        return false;

    return true;
}

private string CreateSql(string value)
{
    return @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
         VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail,(SELECT clientID FROM [CLIENT] WHERE cname='" + value + "'))";
}

    if (!EditFieldsAreValid())
    {
        lblBError.Enabled = true;
        lblBError.Visible = true;
        lblBError.Text = "Please provide the required field.";
        return;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtControl.Text))
    {
        if (DropDownClient.Enabled && DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value == "select")
        {
            lblBError.Enabled = true;
            lblBError.Visible = true;
            lblBError.Text = "Please select Client.";
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lblClientName.Text))
            {
                sql = CreateSql(lblClientName.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                sql = CreateSql(DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sql = CreateSql(txtControl.Text.Trim());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Only the else part of txtControl.text is not executing.Inorder word it does not check for lblClientName....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help. What Mr Tigran pointed out was of great help. I found out that the else statement which the program ignored shouldn't in the place i put it. It rather should b elike this.

```
  if (txtControl.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            if (DropDownClient.Enabled)
            {
                if (DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value == "select")
                {
                    lblBError.Enabled = true;
                    lblBError.Visible = true;
                    lblBError.Text = "Please select Client.";

                    return;

                }
                else
                {
                    sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                    VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value + ")";

                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (lblClientName.Text.Trim() != "")
                {
                    sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                       VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail,(SELECT clientID FROM [CLIENT] WHERE cname='" + lblClientName.Text + "'))";

                }
                else
                {
                    sql = @"INSERT INTO [BRANCH] (bname,baddress,bcity,bstate,bpostcode,bphone,bfax,bemail,clientID)
                       VALUES (@bname,@baddress,@bcity,@bstate,@bpostcode,@bphone,@bfax,@bemail," + DropDownClient.SelectedItem.Value + ")";
                }
            }
```

It took me hours though. Thank you everyone.